# Convert Screen co-ordinates to Prspective camera co-ordinates in libgdx?

Tags: 3d, libgdx, perspectivecamera

I am developing 3d game using libgdx .i have to move my model on touchdrag() .
how can i convert my touch co-ordinates to perspective camera co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `getPickRay` method from camera class to do the same.

```
  public boolean touchDragged(int x, int y, int pointer) {

   Ray ray=Cam.threeDCam.getPickRay(x,y);
   Vector3 tmpVector = new Vector3(); 
   float distance = -ray.origin.y / ray.direction.y;
   tmpVector.set(ray.direction).scl(distance).add(ray.origin);
  }
```

here in tmpVector you have your perspective camera co-ordinates.